# Can't resolve "The type or namespace name 'mshtml' could not be found" error

Tags: visual-studio

I added `Microsoft HTML Object Library` as COM Type Libraries to use `mshtml`.

I could build the project when I used in Visual Studio 2017.
But after updating to Visual Studio 2019, there is a error `The type or namespace name 'mshtml' could not be found`.

I have no idea why the library is not recognized.

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: Please tell me what is wrong with my question if you vote down.

Comment: I didn't downvote but your question is clearly missing a [Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I don't have access to VS2019 atm to verify but you could start a new empty console project in VS2019, add the reference, then use it in one file and build the project. If it builds just fine, you work on a Minimal Reproducible example. If it happens to not build (I doubt that), then it could be a bug in VS2019 or something.

Comment: I see. I thought there is some kind of standard approach to fix library reference error. That was I wanted to know. If there is no such method, I gonna rewrite my project. I'm just learning now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed `Unofficial.Microsoft.mshtml` from NuGet package manager, then the problem was resolved.

I don't know why official dll doesn't work, though.